# how to get an instance of an arraylist which is inside another arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an arraylist inside an arraylist (nested arraylist) as below

```
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> indexOfJSONObject = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Now I need to get an instance of the `arraylist` that exists in a given index of the `indexOfJSONObject` arraylist and add a value to it. I used the following code

```
    ArrayList<Integer> tempJSONObjectAL= (ArrayList<Integer>)indexOfJSONObject.get(givenIndex);

    tempJSONObjectAL.add(value);
```

but it gives me the error of

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

how to fix this and why this happening.

Thank you

Comment: It's not very hard to unserstand the error : 
You want the element at the index 0 , so the first
BUT the list is empty : size = 0
You have apparently not provide any data to indexOfJSONObject

Comment: it's happeninng because `indexOfJSONObject` does not contain any items and per doc spec calling `get` on empty list results in `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: indexOfJSONObject is null at the time you are calling it

Comment: I guess you basically do not have anything within the first location of the arrayList :-) That's basically the reason your'e getting the error IOOBE. As adding an empty arraylist to an arraylist does not make any sense - as the first element will be an empty object :-)
However, if you new ArrayList<> first, then add a new ArrayList<> after that, things will work as intended :-).

Comment: also maybe it would be more convinient and readable to use `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`

Comment: You can first use ArrayList<Integer> tempJSONObjectAL= (ArrayList<Integer>)indexOfJSONObject.getList();..Then get the first object

Comment: @Akshay it say that `getList()` undefined for array list

Comment: Ok...I got it...see my answer

Answer (score 2):

The problem here seems that list size is 0 and you are still trying to access an element at position 0.

You should never try to directly access an element in a collection, without using a loop/iterator or without putting a check comparing size and givenIndex. Your code should be something like

```
ArrayList<Integer> tempJSONObjectAL= null;
if(indexOfJSONObject.size() > givenIndex)
    tempJSONObjectAL = (ArrayList<Integer>)indexOfJSONObject.get(givenIndex);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Reason**This is very simple. This error is because `indexOfJSONObject` is an ArrayList which itself holds an ArrayList. But You haven't any ArrayList inside the indexOfJSONObject.
You are initially getting the ArrayList from indexOfJSONObject, while there is no ArrayList Instantiation inside it.

 *You need to add a new Instantiation of ArrayList to the indexOfJSONObject and then work with it.* 

 By adding one specific statement will solve the issue. Just check my code below:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> indexOfJSONObject = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

//This line of code is required in your case
indexOfJSONObject.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

ArrayList<Integer> tempJSONObjectAL= (ArrayList<Integer>)indexOfJSONObject.get(givenIndex);

tempJSONObjectAL.add(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> indexOfJSONObject = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> tempJSONObjectAL=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(ArrayList<Integer> list:indexOfJSONObject)
        {
            tempJSONObjectAL.add(list.get(index));

        }
```